# duplicate registration for activity "androidstutio"

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="android.testlocalserver">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".confirmActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".confirmActivity"

        android:label="@string/title_activity_confrim"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

Below is the error:

```
error:at android:name=".confirmActivity" 
duplicate registration for activity 
android.testlocalservice.confirmactivity
```

I don't why this is happenning and i read some answers and says select the mode !!
how can i set the mode of activity ,why ?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you have two activities with the same name.
Remove one of them:

```
<activity android:name=".confirmActivity" />  

<activity
    android:name=".confirmActivity"

    android:label="@string/title_activity_confrim"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the error is due to using different flavours,
You can add the flavour identifier before your activity name.

For example)

```
// For Staging
com.example.uat.confirmActivity 

// For Production
com.example.app.confirmActivity
```